Are seeded runs affected by what you have unlocked?
When doing a seeded run in Balatro, there is a note that says “All Unlocks and Discoveries disabled”. Obviously this means you can’t unlock new items during a seeded run, but do the items you have unlocked impact a seeded run?
For example, let’s say there are two players. Player 1 has every joker unlocked while player 2 does not. Player 1 does a seeded run and encounters a joker in the first shop that player 2 hasn’t unlocked. If player 2 does a run with the same seed, will they see different jokers in the shop?


The things you have unlocked do impact your seeded runs in many ways.
A seed I've used to verify this is the following: PKF1939A. When you run it on a fully unlocked profile, you get two "Rare Joker" tags if you skip the first two blinds, which allow you to access a Burnt Joker (a locked one) on the next Joker pack.
If you create a brand new profile and try to launch this same seed, the tags are different already: you get A Charm Tag, and a Boss Tag. The packs' content will also be different and with reasons: a seeded run indeed doesn't show any card you've not unlocked yet.
To explain it, a seeded run will just use the same random value used to generate the game, but this value will be used in coordination with the information of the player's profile. If there's stuff that is locked on this profile, then it won't be accessible in this seed.

A great answer, but you might consider throwing in a link such as this one to help people understand what a "seed" is actually used for.
